Give the result string provided minimum number of parenthesis addition done to make string balanced
A good follow up question asked in one of the interview post 'valid parentheses' problem.
Given an imbalanced parentheses string, return the result string(any one of multiple solutions) with balanced parentheses provided minimum number of parentheses addition is done.
Eg.

"(){([)}()" -> "(){([])}()"
"([)]" -> "([()])" or "()[()]" or "[([])]"

It is easy to get the count of minimum addition needed for balanced string but exact string was tricky and could not come to optimal solution taking minimum addition for getting the string.
I was leaning towards use of recursive/dynamic programming solution evaluating every choice of minimum length balanced substring formed.
Any suggestions/approach would be welcome

Can’t we also have [([])] for the second example?

"I was leaning towards use of recursive/dynamic programming solution": was there a problem with that solution?

Yup [([])] is also one of the soln, you have to give only 1 answer, it can be any of the results. I did not include it since in my mind I was following greedy until point of imbalance and then try to balance it with recursion for 2 choices at that point.

@trincot the problem was I was not able to come up with the recursive method where I will also get minimum addition string.. :P I'm still on it post interview, thought to get some insights from community..

Oh so you require that it is recursive?

Is parsing from left to right and adding a closing bracket whenever needed to fix it to match the opening type (ignore closing brackets that weren't opened yet)) add all missing cling brackets at the right end and than do the same in the opposite direction always a minimal solution? I think I need examples where the 'obvious' solution is not minimal.

@MrSmith42 I think your approach might work, will have to check for some samples though. I also don't have set of samples, since was working with two sample cases for the interview problem at that time.. Probably could get imbalanced string from a balanced string with few deletions..

@trincot not necessarily but IMO recursive would be starting point and then we can think on dynamic programming.. if applicable..

@MrSmith42 I have not looked for an example. But I can imagine that we may sometimes be faced with a choice between adding the right closing bracket to close an open bracket on the stack to be left with having a match for the close bracket we just found, or creating a new open bracket for the close bracket we just found. And which choice is right may depend on how many open/close of each type are in the rest of the string.

It is definitely possible to solve this with an A* search. It is a bit of a PITA to write up though - maybe I'll do that tomorrow if you feel it is needed. (It gets harder still if you don't want to add some O(n) level inefficiencies to it.)

We define text as input parentheses string and:
sol(x, y) = min_addition_count to handle text[x:y]

And sol(x, y) is the minimum of these two cases:
1. sol(x + 1, y - 1) if text[x] and text[y] is match(eg. text[x] is '(' and text[y] is ')')
2. sol(x, i) + sol(i + 1, y) for i >= x and i < y

For the corner cases, we have:
sol(x, y) = 1 for x == y
sol(x, y) = 0 for x > y

During the solving, we record where our solution(the minimum addition account) comes from, and then we can find the solution after we get it.
You can check my Python code for details:
def find_solution(text):
    mem = {}
    # mem[x, y] is a tuple (α, β), where α is the minimum addition count, and β is where α comes from.
    # so β can be 2 cases: [(x + 1, y - 1)] or [(x, x + i), (i + 1, y)]

    def sol(x, y):
        if mem.get((x, y)) is not None:
            return mem[x, y]
        if x > y:
            mem[x, y] = 0, None
            return mem[x, y]
        if x == y:
            mem[x, y] = 1, None
            return mem[x, y]
        ans = len(text), []
        if (text[x] == '(' and text[y] == ')') or (text[x] == '[' and text[y] == ']') or (
                text[x] == '{' and text[y] == '}'):
            if ans[0] >= sol(x + 1, y - 1)[0]: # case1
                ans = sol(x + 1, y - 1)[0], [(x + 1, y - 1)]
                mem[x, y] = ans
        for i in range(x, y):
            if ans[0] >= sol(x, i)[0] + sol(i + 1, y)[0]: # case2
                ans = sol(x, i)[0] + sol(i + 1, y)[0], [(x, i), (i + 1, y)]
                mem[x, y] = ans
        return mem[x, y]

    def get_solution(x, y):
        if x > y:
            return ''
        if x == y:
            t = text[x]
            if t == '(' or t == ')':
                return '()'
            if t == '[' or t == ']':
                return '[]'
            if t == '{' or t == '}':
                return '{}'
        sol = mem[x, y]
        if len(sol[1]) == 1:
            return text[x] + get_solution(*sol[1][0]) + text[y]
        if len(sol[1]) == 2:
            return get_solution(*sol[1][0]) + get_solution(*sol[1][1])

    sol(0, len(text) - 1)
    return get_solution(0, len(text) - 1)


print(find_solution('(){([)}()'))
print(find_solution(')))'))
print(find_solution('([)]'))
print(find_solution('()()'))
print(find_solution('()[()}'))
print(find_solution('({)[]'))

Output:
(){([])}()
()()()
([])[]
()()
()[](){}
({})[]

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to comment here.

What does sol(i + 1, x) for i >= x mean? How can the first parameter of sol be allowed to be greater than its second parameter?

@Sayakiss the above code went out through my head, could you please add some comments in major steps? I'm noob for Python..

@גלעדברקן It's a mistake, it should be sol(x, i) + sol(i + 1, y). I edited my answer.

@Shailendra I think it is because you are unfamiliar with dynamic programming by memorization. You can check this article to learn how to handle a simpler task: https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-recursion-memoization-and-dynamic-programming-3-sides-of-the-same-coin-8c1f57ee5604

@Shailendra I added some comments to help you to catch up. It would be better to read that article first.

Thanks, I was not able to follow the data structures/dictionary used for dp since I am not familiar with Python. I'll see the comments.
